# grabbing results and subresults in 1 query php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

What if I have a table as following

```
id | mother_id | subject | date
1 | 0 | test1 | 122344
2 | 0 | test2 | 122335
3 | 1 | reply1totest1 | 122499
4 | 1 | reply2totest1 | 122734
5 | 2 | reply1totest2 | 126887
```

And I would like PHP to produce HTML which would look like this:

```
reply1totest1
 - reply1totest1 
 - test1 
reply1totest2 
 - test2
```

What I am trying to say is, I would like them grouped together, but with the last reply on top. Also would like this to be done in 1 query, coz I could do it and then reverse the query, but I wanna do it nice and neat with 1 query...

Comment: You'd better perform 2 separated queries. The such sorting could be a bit tricky and not performant.

Comment: the thing is, it wont be 2 queries, it will be 1 which selects all where mother_id is 0 and then on all those results go about and select the subitems where mother_id is the ID of the result.

Comment: Yes, and it is 2 queries: 1) select all 2) `WHERE mother_id IN (1, 2)` or just `JOIN`, as you wish

Comment: I don't understand how you get from your sample data to your desired output.  test1 and test2 both have a 0 mother_id, so they should be top-most, with reply1totest1 and reply2totest1 under test1 and reply1totest2 under that.

Comment: Does the table have only two levels or is it fully hierarchical with any level of nesting?

Answer (score 0):

I must say that table structure does not allow one single query, i mean 2 queries by (select from (select)) because that is not a single query, there is a missing key to identify all items from one thread, so you have to crawl thorw hierarchical design.

I think we got left some question.

Can't you modify the thable structure? and/or insertion method? - I though no because you are asking to solve this sort.

I figured an hypothetical single query, just in case there is no "reply to reply", first you have to run this sql statement

```
update 'table' set mother_id=id where mother_id=0;
```

Next, you can do the sort query by

```
select mother_id,subject from 'table' order by mother_id asc,id desc
```

I add 'id' to the query so you can do the visual presentation with value change detect when looping to array result

I hope it helps a little

Answer (score -2):

1 Query would be impossible because retrieval itself would require multiple queries. Have you checked out join? tigzag references it pretty nicely, just google it! :)

Comment: It's certainly not impossible to get the data in one query, it's just not 100% clear how the data is retrieved yet, renevdkooi needs to clarify a bit.  Besides that, general references to tutorial sites are not very helpful and "just google it" is even less helpful.  A link to a specific tutorial may help, preferably including a title and quote, or a link to specific google search results with terms renevdkooi may not have thought of that brings up results that are clearly relevant.

Comment: He would be using a join statement which retrieves more then 1 query. You're just stupid sir, so please do not reply with such nonsense.:)